# Assign a key's value in an array as the return of a function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

[I have a plugin on my wordpress site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/our-team-by-woothemes/) that allows me to create team members. I am putting code into my author.php file of my child theme to display the 'Our Team' plugin content on the author archive page. The plugin instructs hard coding the template [like so (look at usage examples).](http://wordpress.org/plugins/our-team-by-woothemes/other_notes/) I need to use the `slug` argument to get the author's 'Our Team' information; this is what I'm doing:

In author.php in my child theme:

```
    <?php
      do_action( 'woothemes_our_team', array(
        'slug' => the_author_meta('user_nicename'),   // This line is the problem
        'display_author_archive'  => false,
        )
      );
    ?>
```

You can see how I want to use the returned value of the `the_author_meta()` function as the value for the `slug` key in the array. However, this does not return the correct result. Instead I get the slug output to the template and every team member name listed underneath that. Using `the_author_meta('user_nicename')` outputs the correct info when I take it out of the array. Assigning it to a variable did not work either:

```
    <?php
      $test = the_author_meta('user_nicename');
      do_action( 'woothemes_our_team', array(
        'slug' => $test,
        'display_author_archive'  => false,
        )
      );
    ?>
```

Hard coding the slug makes the function work the intended way:

```
    <?php
      $test = 'cleo-g';
      do_action( 'woothemes_our_team', array(
        'slug' => $test,
        'display_author_archive'  => false,
        )
      );
    ?>
```

The above will output the correct 'Our Team' plugin content to the template. Why is it that when the `the_author_meta('user_nicename')` function outputs the correct data it will not work inside the array as a key value, or even if I assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. See the Note at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta:

> NOTE: Use `get_the_author_meta()` if you need to return (not display) the information.